# Wrong int values using struct and arrays

Tags: c

Hello I have a problem with integer. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct data
{
    char name[50];
    int grade[1];
};

int main()
{
    struct data persons[30];
    int n = 3;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Type person name nr: [%d] ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",persons[i].name);
        printf("Type grade: (from 1 to 6) ");
        scanf("%d",persons[i].grade);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Name [%d]: %s\n",i+1,persons[i].name);
        printf("Grade [%d]: %d\n",i+1,persons[i].grade);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And when I type some names and grades the output isn't correct:
[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYDBn.png)

Comment: Your compiler should've printed some warnings. If not, compile with `-Wall`.

Comment: The correct way `&persons[i].grade`. Please,  use `-Wall` and `-Werror` flags every time when compiling your program.

Comment: This is probably the millionth question on SO regarding missing & in scanf. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: Also, `int grade[1];` declares an array of 1 integer. While there are legitimate uses for a one-element array (in certain cases where you want an address to provide allocation beyond the struct itself, such as when implementing a memory allocation scheme) -- this isn't one. If you simply need one `int`, declare `int grade;` and remove the `[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an array for a single grade, when a standard int is enough.

```
struct data
{
    char name[50];
    int grade;
};
```

And then you also need to pass the reference of the int to scanf using an &.

```
scanf("%d", &persons[i].grade);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that in this way. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

The corrected version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
    char name[50];
    int grade; // In you case, to store one integer value just use int varibale because it seems more logical.
};

int main() {
    struct data persons[30];
    int n = 3;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Type person name nr: [%d] ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", persons[i].name);
        printf("Type grade: (from 1 to 6) ");
        scanf("%d", &persons[i].grade); // To fill member of structure you may use '&' sign because scanf gets address.
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Name [%d]: %s\n", i + 1, persons[i].name);
        printf("Grade [%d]: %d\n", i + 1, persons[i].grade);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Also, keep in mind that compiler not always tell you that something is going to be wrong, in most cases using special flags (some of them I mentioned in the comment) for compiler can give you more information.

It's worth to note that current IDEs highlight obvious errors and really speed up your development process.

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace

```
printf("Grade [%d]: %d\n",i+1,persons[i].grade);
```

by

```
printf("Grade [%d]: %d\n",i+1,persons[i].grade[0]);
```

in the scanf you do `scanf("%d",persons[i].grade);` so because *grade* is a vector you give its address, but in the *printf* you have to specify the index else you print the address of the vector

However to use a vector is useless because it contains only one element, better to directly use an *int* for grade, and of course in that case you have to give `&persons[i].grade` for the *scanf* and `persons[i].grade` for 
the *printf*

---

Execution :

```
Type person name nr: [1] a
Type grade: (from 1 to 6) 1
Type person name nr: [2] b
Type grade: (from 1 to 6) 2
Type person name nr: [3] c
Type grade: (from 1 to 6) 3
Name [1]: a
Grade [1]: 1
Name [2]: b
Grade [2]: 2
Name [3]: c
Grade [3]: 3
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the result is the same.

Comment: @AdrianFlis I don't know how you did your test but that works !

Answer (score 0):

It's because `grade` is an array, so you need to do `.grade[0]`when writing or reading data to / from it, like so:

```
scanf("%d",persons[i].grade[0]);
...
printf("Grade [%d]: %d\n",i+1,persons[i].grade[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is working. I dont know why someone down reputate you

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: `scanf("%d",persons[i].grade[0]);` must be `scanf("%d",&persons[i].grade[0]);`